# What is the difference between ArrayList al = new ArrayList<String>(); and ArrayList al = new ArrayList();?

Tags: java, object, generics, arraylist, collections

what is the difference between these two? in the first case why it allows int value in ArrayList?

```
                     ArrayList al = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                     al.add(1);
                     al.add(2);
                     System.out.println(al.get(1));
```

Comment: You should be using either `ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();` or `List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();`.

Comment: without the <> is older java. It doesn't say what is going to be inside the list. So you can put inside whatever you want. Notice that this is bad practice. So as the comment above said. Use the one with <>

Comment: @JoãoCosta I would say more strongly than *older* Java, it's *15-year-old* Java (Generics were introduced in 2005 with Java 5).